# How to init text input for Arabic / Persian keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, keyboard

I'm trying to make a text input that change keyboard type from English to Persian / Arabic , totally is any solution for type on to the text input without hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> to change keyboard type with javascript or css ?

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> is windows shortcut for changing keyboard between defined languages . it's OS functionality and not related to browser(s) . [here is](http://hasheminezhad.com/kblayout) the jQuery plugin for typing Farsi/Arabic by default

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: you can find its archive here : 

https://web.archive.org/web/20160625151900/https://hasheminezhad.com/kblayout